# Versioning on db models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, versioning

I have location and user model, each location has multiple users was my previous design. location has_many users. location_id stored in user model as FK.

Now I have to store each user with multiple location_id in join(through) model. user has_many locations through location_users(join table). Is it possible database versioning in rails?

Comment: Your question is very unclear so quite why it has been upvoted I have no idea. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do